# Creating a Json request and getting Json objects

Tags: android, json, google-places-api

I am following along with [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android) about how to use Google Places API with auto complete in Android.

This gets the description of the predictions and stores them in an array to be shown when the user is typing in their string.

```
private ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String input) {
        ArrayList<String> resultList = null;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL mUrl = new URL(PLACES_API_BASE +
                    TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE +
                    OUT_JSON +
                    "?sensor=false&key=" +
                    API_KEY +
                    "&components=country:us" +
                    "&input=" +
                    URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) mUrl.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Load the results into a StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        try {
            // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            mPredictionsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

            // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
            resultList = new ArrayList<String>(mPredictionsJsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < mPredictionsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                resultList.add(mPredictionsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        return resultList;
    }
```

then, when the user clicks on the suggestion;

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
        //String reference = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=";
        //String photo = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=70&photoreference=";

        try {
            REFERENCE = mPredictionsJsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("reference");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
        }

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            REFERENCE = mPredictionsJsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("reference");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
        }

        try {
            URL mUrl = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=" +
                    REFERENCE +
                    "?sensor=false&key=" +
                    API_KEY);

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) mUrl.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Load the results into a StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
```

**logcat**

```
02-18 10:59:27.775    2081-2081/com.example.project.thisthat E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.project.thisthat, PID: 2081
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
            at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.close(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:1009)
            at com.android.okhttp.Connection.close(Connection.java:175)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.Util.closeQuietly(Util.java:110)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.release(HttpEngine.java:447)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.disconnect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:104)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.disconnect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:124)
            at com.example.project.thisthat.PollActivity.onItemClick(PollActivity.java:175)
            at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.performCompletion(AutoCompleteTextView.java:902)
            at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.access$500(AutoCompleteTextView.java:91)
            at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView$DropDownItemClickListener.onItemClick(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1192)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2904)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3638)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am able to get the reference number for the item selected, however, when I try to replicate the above code in the `onItemClick()` function, i get a fatal error and the application force closes. 
I am trying to eventually get the photo URL for the place selected.

Comment: please share logcat result and code which you are using inside `onItemClick` to call `autocomplete`

Comment: I guess the NetworkOnMainThreadException ;)

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK updated with full code and logcat

Comment: @A.S. you are right, what does that mean?

Comment: Hey please do all network stuff in a seperate thread like AsyncTask, there are many crappy tuts out there doing the network stuff in UI-Thread, but this will cause this failure. Just google for `Network Request AsyncTask Android`

Comment: @A.S. what happens if I need to use multiple URLs, to get different strings? Is it all done in one AsyncTask?

Comment: @EricLemos That depends on how you wish to implement it. I suppose you can do it all in one AsyncTask, but I can imagine that you're dealing with different parameters and results for all requests so this might be troublesome.

Comment: Would it be okay to create multiple AsyncTask for each url I need to build? (getReference, getPhotoReference, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have alluded to, you can certainly create a new AsyncTask in each OnItemClick. Behind the scenes, the Android system shares threads for AsyncTasks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you are getting:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

which means that you are trying to execute a network call on the main thread, the best approach would be to use an Asynctask and get the data in the asyncTask and then send the data from the onPostExecute()  method of the asynctask to the main thread in order to update the UI.

References for asyncTask [1], [2].

[1] http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

[2] http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html#.UwQ2J2KSx1Y